# Through lines textbox startwith and endswith something

Tags: vb.net

in my File Text I have the following things:
I have to make it start from somewhere and stop at a certain point.
but he only starts from that point, but he does not know how to stop at one point.

```
[Letters]
A
B
C
D
E
[Loop]
[Words]
Fish
Facebook
Google
Youtube
```

I should display Expected Output:

```
A
B
C
D
E
```

Then I should make it display

```
Fish
Facebook
Google
Youtube
```

but it shows me:

```
[Letters]
A
B
C
D
E
[Loop]
[Words]
Fish
Facebook
Google
Youtube
```

Code

```
   Dim line As String
        Using reader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(My.Application.Info.DirectoryPath & "\TestReader.txt")
            line = reader.ReadLine
            Dim sb As New StringBuilder
            Do
                Do
                    If reader.Peek < 0 Then 'Check that you haven't reached the end
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    line = reader.ReadLine
                    If line.StartsWith("[Letters]") AndAlso line.EndsWith("[Loop]") Then 'Check if we have reached another check box.
                        Exit Do
                    End If
                    sb.AppendLine(line)
                Loop
                TextBox1.Text = sb.ToString
            sb.Clear()
            Loop Until reader.Peek < 0
        End Using
```

Comment: to make it display A B C D E, now it displays them all. that is, to be able to start it from somewhere, and stop where they want. that is, once I display [Letters] and using that code, I can modify it to display [Words]

Comment: To start from [Letters] that is to display A B C D E and to stop it at [Words]

Comment: If you start at [LETTERS] stop at [WORDS], then why wouldn’t [LOOP] be included?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This assumes that `startPrefix` and `endPrefix` will always be present in the file:

```vb
Dim startPrefix As String 'Set as required
Dim endPrefix As String 'Set as required

Dim lines As New List(Of String)

Using reader As New StreamReader("file path here")
    Dim line As String

    'Skip lines up to the first starting with the specified prefix.
    Do
        line = reader.ReadLine()
    Loop Until line.StartsWith(startPrefix)

    line = reader.ReadLine()

    Do Until line.StartsWith(endPrefix)
        lines.Add(line)
        line = reader.ReadLine()
    Loop
End Using

'Use lines here.
```

Are you really sure that you want to look for lines that start with those markers though? Wouldn't you really prefer to look for lines that are equal to those markers?

EDIT:

You could - and probably should - encapsulate that functionality in a method:

```vb
Private Function GetLinesBetween(filePath As String, startPrefix As String, endPrefix As String) As String()
    Dim lines As New List(Of String)

    Using reader As New StreamReader(filePath)
        Dim line As String

        'Skip lines up to the first starting with the specified prefix.
        Do
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop Until line.StartsWith(startPrefix)

        line = reader.ReadLine()

        'Take lines up to the first starting with the specified prefix.
        Do Until line.StartsWith(endPrefix)
            lines.Add(line)
            line = reader.ReadLine()
        Loop
    End Using

    Return lines.ToArray()
End Function
```

Comment: I don't know exactly what he means. does the code improve to run faster?

Comment: @FatirRizky, I mean that you should write your code to do what you actually want to do. Are you intending the file to always contain a line that contains "[Letters]" and that is where you want to start reading or would it sometimes contain "[Letters]some more arbitrary text here"? If you never intend to have something like the latter then why would you write your code to look for something like the latter? If the line is supposed to be exactly the value you specify then you should be looking for lines that are exactly that, not lines that start with it and end with anything at all.